# How to feed patient data to tflite file model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I have the patient data I need in an excel file, and I need to feed that data to a tflite file. Could someone point me in the right direction to do this using python, please (preferably a code template)? I've looked up code templates but none of them seem to work with what I have to work with.

Comment: I think you are confused. A `.tflite` file is a representation of a tensorflow model, made so that it is easy to run in mobile devices. So, you have to read the data from the excel file (using a tool like pandas), then load the tflite model and finally pass the input to that model to make inference.